# Issue with mysql insert query in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables. The same query works fine with one table but doesn't work with the other one.

Query which works fine:

```
$qry="insert into table_a (product_id, image_name) VALUES ('$a1', '$name1')";
$result = @mysql_query($qry);
```

Query which is not inserting data into the table:

```
$qry=("insert into subtable(product_id, title, desc) VALUES ({$a1}, {$a2}, {$a3})");
$result = @mysql_query($qry);
```

Comment: Get rid of the `@` in front of your query and use mysql_error() for error reporting.

Comment: using `@` in php is the equivalent of "on error resume next" in VBA, and definitely the equivalent of stuffing your fingers into your ears and going "lalalalaalala can't hear you". If you won't listen to what PHP has to tell you, why should we try to help you?

Comment: @MarcB: Not quite, PHP will halt on the next error in the script - VBA just keeps on going!

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) like the ones you have here. Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and is a safer way to compose queries. `$_POST` data never goes directly in a query.

Answer (score 3):

`desc` is a reserved word which must be wrapped in backticks.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

use:

```
(product_id, title, `desc`)
```

and do as John Conde stated in his [comment:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537388/issue-with-mysql-insert-query-in-php/21537473#comment32523002_21537388)

*("Get rid of the `@` in front of your query and use [`mysql_error()`](http://www.php.net/mysql_error) for error reporting.")*

or wrap them all in backticks

```
(`product_id`, `title`, `desc`)
```

Rewrite:

```
$qry=("insert into subtable (`product_id`, `title`, `desc`) VALUES ({$a1}, {$a2}, {$a3})");
$result = mysql_query($qry);
```

And do use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/mysqli) with [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

- [**How to avoid SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)